# Indexing [::-1] to Reverse ALL 2D Array Rows and ALL 3D and 4D Array Columns and Rows Simultaneously Python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, matrix-indexing

How do you get indexing [::-1] to reverse ALL 2D array rows and ALL 3D and 4D array columns and rows simultaneously? I can only get indexing [::-1] to reverse 2D array columns. Python

```
import numpy as np

randomArray = np.round(10*np.random.rand(5,4))
sortedArray = np.sort(randomArray,axis=1)
reversedArray = sortedArray[::-1]
# reversedArray = np.flip(sortedArray,axis=1)

print('Random Array:')
print(randomArray,'\n')
print('Sorted Array:')
print(sortedArray,'\n')
print('Reversed Array:')
print(reversedArray)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse a dimensions of a `numpy` array depending on where you place the `::-1`.

Lets take a 3D array. For reversing the first dimension:

```
reversedArray = sortedArray[::-1,:,:]
```

For reversing the second dimension:

```
reversedArray = sortedArray[:,::-1,:]
```

For reversing the third dimension:

```
reversedArray = sortedArray[:,:,::-1]
```

Comment: At joostblack...[:,::-1,:] is the only index that worked to reverse 3D array columns, and it reversed all of the columns simultaneously. [:,:,::-1] is the only index that worked to reverse 3D array rows, and it reversed all of the rows simultaneously. [:,::-1] worked to reverse 2D array rows, and it reversed all of the rows simultaneously. [:,:,::-1,:] worked to reverse 4D array columns, and it reversed all of the columns simultaneously. [:,:,:,::-1] worked to reverse 4D array rows, and it reversed all of the rows simultaneously. All indexes worked like I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: glad I could help

Comment: Yes, I was able to figure out the index to reverse all 4D array columns simultaneously and 4D array rows simultaneously from the indexes you provided. And I forgot that I already had from another source the index to reverse all 2D array rows simultaneously before I posted this thread, but I put the answer in here anyway in case someone else needs it. Again, thanks!